# SQLite date function returns nothing

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, statistics, data-science

I have a dataset with column named "msg_dateStr" which contains user's accessing date and time.
I tried to split it into two different columns; date and time, and I did `SELECT date(msg_dateStr, 'localtime') as Year`
 but it returns null straight.
I don't know why this happens and how I can make sure something went wrong.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of that `msg_dateStr` column? I bet it's not in the list of formats that date and time functions accept, listed at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

The date to be used by the [Date and Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) such as **date** MUST be in a format that is recognised by SQLite for a useful result. Recognised formats are (extract from the link above) :-

> ### Time Strings
>
> **A time string can be in any of the following formats:**
>
> ```
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```

You need to ensure that the data is saved accordingly or alternately (but not recommended at all) reformat the column via SQL (e.g. using the substr built-in function).